# Trap Windows application crash and flush file buffers

Tags: c++, winapi, crash, flush

This question is a bit far-out, but I thought maybe someone knows a clever solution.

I have a particular situation with an RTS game in Windows (*Kane's Wrath*), which saves replay files. It is possible for an adverse opponent to trigger a crash in the game. In that event, having as complete a replay file as possible would be advantageous.

However, the replay file output seems to be buffered and only occurs in sets of 4096 bytes (which is a lot of game time). I am wondering if it is possible somehow to force the program to flush all its file handles in the event of a crash. Is there a some built-in OS feature that allows disabling of buffering for an application?

Failing that, I might like to write a launcher/wrapper for this problem. I imagine that it should inject some code which a) installs a signal handler for the crash (is it SIGSEGV?), and b) redirects `CreateFile` (which I know the program uses from following a trace) to store the handle. The crash handler would then just flush all the handlers with [`FlushFileBuffers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Or is it perhaps possible to obtain another process's open file handles?

Would this have a chance of working, and could you give me any advice on how to best achieve this with the least amount of intrusion?

---

*Little update:* @CatPlusPlus has suggested [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to hook into the program, intercept file opening calls and modify them to be unbuffered. This may well be the solution!

Comment: There's no built-in OS feature to do that, how could there possibly be?  The OS has no idea that buffering is even happening -- all it sees is that, every so often, someone says "hey, I want to write 4096 bytes to this file" and it does it.

Comment: @Adam: Well, similar to on Linux you have `ulimit` to tell a program not to do certain things. I thought maybe the OS can just say, "for this next process we disable all IO buffering", since the IO uses system calls ultimately.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could start by wrapping winmain in a try/catch block like is described in this 
article:

[XCrashReport : Exception Handling and Crash Reporting - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/XCrashReportPt1.aspx?display=Print)

which basically does something like this:

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, LPTSTR lpstrCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    int Result = -1;
    __try
    {
        Result = HandledWinMain(hInstance, NULL, lpstrCmdLine, nCmdShow);
    }

    __except(RecordExceptionInfo(hInstance,GetExceptionInformation(), "main thread"))
    {
        // Do nothing here - RecordExceptionInfo() has already done
        // everything that is needed. Actually this code won't even
        // get called unless you return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER from
        // the __except clause.
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Of course I'm not sure what the state of your buffers will be, but this will allow you to hook into the process.

Comment: Can I catch exceptions from another program with this? Remember, I do not have the source code of the game program, only the executable. I somehow have to get the excutable's file handles and trap the crash.

Comment: not sure that is possible without attaching a debugger, and that might not give you anything useful, you also might want to see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385859/is-it-possible-for-a-process-to-catch-an-unhandled-exception-of-another-process-o

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the process is not yours, 
your only option seems to be hooking WriteFile function, and do instead a WriteFile followed by a Flush.
WriteFile can be hooked by [IAT](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/system/misc/article.php/c5667) hooking directy or using a library like [eashook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I was thinking about hooking `CreateFile` instead and change the flags to unbuffered, which according to MSDN is "like calling `FlushFileBuffers` after every write but more efficient"...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to attach a debugger and tinker in its assembler output.

I remember doing this with some programs when they crashed on me: Jump over the offending machine instructions to the end of the function, and let it run. in about 50% of all cases that would let the program get to a point where I could save my data. Of course, restarting afterwards was mandatory.

Comment: Well, I'd like to be able to ship this as a single launcher application that wraps the game, or something like that, so it should be non-interactive if possible...